# 'Tony Stonem' type in classical literature

Tags: character, skins

So there is that [**'Skins'** UK series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skins_(UK_TV_series)) and its central character in the first two seasons [**Tony Stonem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Stonem).

In nature, he is an antagonistic due to his antisocial tendencies. However, he excels in giving a veneer of a good boy for all adults. He seems to be a so-called all parents' dream. But only *'seems'* because his peers know his real nature of a lust for manipulation and cruel games.

Some time ago, I read an article on his personality where his type was said to be like those of a character in a classical either US, or British book. It's a boy who beats up and humiliates his peers. But adults don't know about that and like him a lot thinking he is an ideal child.

The problem is that I forgot the name of that boy in a book. And since I'm not good in US / British classic literature, I can't remeber the book's title.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Although not an example in literature, the same archetype of Tony can also be found in "Leave It To Beaver", (a well-known American 50s sitcom) with a character named "Eddie Haskell."

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Haskell

Eddie was largely known for sucking up/feeding insincere compliments to adults while manipulating and messing with his friends under wraps. His name is often quoted in other tv shows to describe characters of the same achetype; other characters, such as Bart Simpson from The Simpsons, have taken inspiration from Eddie Haskell as well.